# download a file from a Remote Server to my Localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to copy a video file from a remote server to my localhost , so I have:

```
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");
const path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\views\admin\files\session\trimed\oblivin.mp4';

example()

async function example() {
  const client = new ftp.Client()
  client.ftp.verbose = true
  try {
    await client.access({
      host: "****",
      user: "****",
      password: "****",
      secure: false
    });
    await client.ensureDir("movies");
    console.log(await client.list());
    await client.downloadTo(path, "oblivin.mp4");
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
  }
```

But it just create a file with 0 mb of size in local!

How to fix this?

Comment: `await client.downloadTo([path, "oblivin.mp4");` Is this your actually code?   It's missing a closing `]`, and looking at the source it expects a `Writeable` here anyway..

Comment: the `]` was a mistake here, I edited the question. but the issue still exist.

Comment: The document just used a path!!! what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using php script to achieve this.... here is the code:

```
<?php  // define some variables  
  $local_file = 'myfile.zip';  // local path
  $server_file = 'server.zip'; // Server file 
  // set up basic connection  
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);  // ftp host
  // login with username and password  
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);  
  // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file  
  if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))   
  {  
      echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";  
  }   
  else  
  {  
    echo "There was a problem\n";  
  }  
  // close the connection  
  ftp_close($conn_id);  
  ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below code:

```
fetch('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\views\admin\files\session\trimed\oblivin.mp4').then(resp => resp.blob()).then(blob => {
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.style.display = 'none';
a.href = url;
// change the filename as you want to download
a.download = 'todo-1.json';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
alert('your file has downloaded!'); }).catch(() => alert('Error occurred!'));
```

Comment: `fetch` is not `ftp`..

Comment: I want to download from a remote server!

Comment: First answer I see, could/should be improved for SO level of content: You do not say which language/framework you used nor explain what the code is doing